# Watching for file changes, PHP vs NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, file

I need to build a HTTP API which will be used to watch for changes in files in web directory. I can use either PHP or NodeJS to do this, but I would prefer to do it with PHP. I read it is possible to do it using PHP inotify extension (since my host is Linux), or chokidar NodeJS library.

I already tried to implement this in NodeJS, and it works. I used HTTP long pooling, so client can be notified when file changes. But the problem is that besides this API other parts of application will be written in PHP, so I'm not sure is it necessary and generally a good practice to use both technologies together like this.

My question is, is there a better way to do this and if there is how, and generally would it be better to use PHP or NodeJS to watch for file changes ?

Also I'm not sure if my hosting provider provides inotify PHP extension.

Comment: You could use a hash of the files you're interested in, and keep track of changes that way. Note that an API can have multiple users so you have to store 3 data points: user, file path and last  hash, for each request. On a subsequent request you can then compare the hash against the previously stored hash.

Comment: I was also thinking of using file timestamps, that way i would know when file was modified. But if I'm correct this will not allow me to watch for changes in real time. Basically what I'm actually trying to do is to auto refresh page when it's file is changed.

Comment: Sounds like step 1 is finding out if your host has the extension, because otherwise what's the point?

Comment: _If_ you decide to go down the PHP path, and _if_ you are not able to install that extension, you should also be aware of the [stat cache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

Comment: Can your PHP API wrap the NodeJS service, so that from a consumer standpoint it feels unified? I think that's the path I'd go down, at least for V1. This should also allow you to swap the service to PHP in the future if you so decide. Whether one is better than the other is going to be subjective

Comment: inotify is definitely going to be a better choice than continuous stat polling. If your hosting provider doesn't allow it, then you probably want to start looking at VPS or containerized hosting rather than some 90's-era shared service. Also might want to look at SSE (maybe with [Mercure](https://mercure.rocks/)) or websockets (maybe with [React](https://reactphp.org/)) over long polling.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I think I will use NodeJS for now, since I believe chokidar library also uses inotify behind the scenes. Also my hosting provider does not support inotify PHP extension by default, and it seems like using PHP introduces some additional complications. About websockets, they were my first choice but again i had some problems with hosting so I started using HTTP long pooling.

Comment: If you have a satisfactory answer, consider answering your own question.